# PersistGate null state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit, redux-persist

So I'm working on this Facebook clone and I see error
'Uncaught TypeError: user is null'.
Removing PersistGate component from my index.js file works, but I can't figure out how to solve the problem. And I need that component. Here's my code.

index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import authReducer from "./state";
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import {
  persistStore,
  persistReducer,
  FLUSH,
  REHYDRATE,
  PAUSE,
  PERSIST,
  PURGE,
  REGISTER,
} from "redux-persist";
import storage from "redux-persist/lib/storage";
import { PersistGate } from "redux-persist/integration/react";

const persistConfig = { key: "root", storage, version: 1 };
const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, authReducer);
const store = configureStore({
  reducer: persistedReducer,
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware({
      serializableCheck: {
        ignoredActions: [FLUSH, REHYDRATE, PAUSE, PERSIST, PURGE, REGISTER],
      },
    }),
});

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistStore(store)}>
        <App />
      </PersistGate>
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const initialState = {
  mode: "dark",
  user: null,
  token: null,
  posts: [],
};

export const authSlice = createSlice({
  name: "auth",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setMode: (state) => {
      state.mode = state.mode === "light" ? "dark" : "light";
    },
    setLogin: (state, action) => {
      state.user = action.payload.user;
      state.token = action.payload.token;
    },
    setLogout: (state) => {
      state.user = null;
      state.token = null;
    },
    setFriends: (state, action) => {
      if (state.user) {
        state.user.friends = action.payload.friends;
      } else {
        console.error("user friends non-existent :(");
      }
    },
    setPosts: (state, action) => {
      state.posts = action.payload.posts;
    },
    setPost: (state, action) => {
      const updatedPosts = state.posts.map((post) => {
        if (post._id === action.payload.post._id) return action.payload.post;
        return post;
      });
      state.posts = updatedPosts;
    },
  },
});

export const { setMode, setLogin, setLogout, setFriends, setPosts, setPost } = authSlice.actions;
export default authSlice.reducer;
```

I was trying to follow with redux-persist documentation, but couldn't solve the problem.

Comment: It's unclear how you got from *that* error to it being a redux-persist issue. Can you [edit] the post to include the complete error message and code stacktrace? In other words, where exactly in your code does the error/issue start?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the issue may be that you are creating a new persistor anytime the `PersistGate` component rerenders for whatever reason. It's the only part of your setup where I see it deviate from the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-persist#basic-usage).

I suggest creating the `persistor` once outside any React/JSX code.

```
const persistConfig = { key: "root", storage, version: 1 };

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, authReducer);

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: persistedReducer,
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware({
      serializableCheck: {
        ignoredActions: [FLUSH, REHYDRATE, PAUSE, PERSIST, PURGE, REGISTER],
      },
    }),
});

const persistor = persistStore(store); // <-- create outside JSX

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
        <App />
      </PersistGate>
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to reInstall Redux DevTool on your extension (ex: googleChrom) and than observe the states on the window Redux DevTool not on the brower devtool. Sometime it can give anything and sometime with some refresh it will be working on the extension tool and not on the browser "redux devTool". It take me 1 day to obeserve that my code was ok and it was only the Redux Devtool extension that might be the problem.